# Reading PersistentCollections in Twig as if they were an Array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship between two classes (Protocol and History). While searching for a specific Protocol, I'm expected to see all History entries associated with that protocol.

While rendering my template, I pass the following:

```
return $this->render('FunarbeProtocoloAdminBundle:Protocolo:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        'history' => $entity->getHistory(),
    )
);
```

`entity->getHistory()` returns a PersistentCollection instead of an array, which causes the following to render an error:

```
{% for hist in history %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ hist.dtOcorrencia|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
    <td>{{ hist.dtRetorno|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If instead of `$entity->getHistory()` I pass `$em->getRepository('MyBundle:History')->findByProtocol($entity)`, it works fine. But I figure the main point of having a bidirectional relationship was to avoid opening repositories and explicitly opening new resultsets.

Am I doing something wrong? How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do was call the following on my TWIG:

```
{% for hist in entity.history %}
```

None of the other answers worked for me. I have to call the property directly in my twig instead of using its getter. Don't know why, but it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
return $this->render('FunarbeProtocoloAdminBundle:Protocolo:show.html.twig',
    array(
         'entity'      => $entity,
         'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
         'history'     => $entity->getHistory()->toArray()                                                    
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, I always save myself the trouble and get my collections in the twig instead of passing it through my view. You could try this too.

**Render code change**

```
return $this->render('FunarbeProtocoloAdminBundle:Protocolo:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    )
);
```

You want to access the history directly in your twig.

**Twig**

```
{% for hist in entity.getHistory() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ hist.dtOcorrencia|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
        <td>{{ hist.dtRetorno|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If your result after the change is the same, try checking hist for an array, it could be nested! Persistent Collections tend to do that...

```
{% for history in entity.getHistory() %}
    {% for hist in history %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ hist.dtOcorrencia|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
            <td>{{ hist.dtRetorno|date('d/m/Y H:i') }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```